# Using Javascript and PHP to delete an item out of database

Tags: javascript, php

I am using an anchor tag to run the JS function confirm(), and if the user clicks okay it adds "deltopic=id", and use the $_GET method to get 'deltopic' to delete that specific item, but it seems to not be finding the $_GET['deltopic']

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text>
  function deltopic(title, tid) {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to delete '" + title + "'")){
      window.location.href = "?viewtopic.php&deltopic=" + tid;
    }
  }
</script>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['deltopic'])){
if($_GET['deltopic'] !=='1'){
    $query = "DELETE FROM `bkg`.`bkg_topics` WHERE `bkg_topics`.`topic_id` = :topicid";
    $query_params = array(':topicid' => $_GET['deltopic']);
    try{

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

        header('Location: index.php?forums&action=deleted');
        exit;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = "An error has occured. Please try again later.";
    }

}
echo "deltopic is set";
}
```

I added the last echo just to see if its checking if `deltopic` isset, or if it was an error in my SQL that I was just not seeing. However I do not see "deltopic is set".

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and/or what I am forgetting. I have code similar to this, that does work, and double checked it closely.

EDIT: I saw the error I was doing in my 'window.location.href' string, where I was adding .php to the end of ?viewtopic, making it `?viewtopic.php`. Removing the .php fixed my issue as well.

Comment: Try `window.location.href = "viewtopic.php?deltopic=" + tid;`

Comment: Although, ajax through jquery would be a lot better

Comment: I am not too familiar with using ajax & mysql databases. I changed it to `window.location.href = "viewtopic.php?deltopic=" +id;`, ran into some other problems but figured it out ^.^ Thanks.

Comment: If you want to try AJAX, please peak at jQuery implementation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 
Otherwise, please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "?viewtopic.php&deltopic=" + tid;
```

will result in URL where "viewtopic.php" is a part of URL **QUERY**. Perhaps you want it in the **PATH**:

```
window.location.href = "viewtopic.php?deltopic=" + tid;
```

Comment: Ahh I actually may see the error I may have done. In my index.php I use the $_GET method to retrieve what information to display on the page, depending on what $_GET is set. When I had `?viewtopic.php&deltopic="+ tid;` I didn't mean for the ".php" part to be in there.

Comment: Awesome! We do not see the PHP file name in your question, so I have presumed it's "viewtopic.php". Thank you.

Comment: Looking forward, I suggest you use **$_REQUEST** instead of **$_GET** to cover both "post" and "get": will be handy if you switch to ajax.